# WPF - DependencyProperty ignoring setter with side-effects on change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a WPF user control that is a wrapper for two other controls, showing only one of them depending on the situation. It possesses an `ItemsSource` property which sets the `ItemsSource` for the two underlying controls. I want to make it so that this property can be bound to on a .xaml file.

I created a `DependencyProperty`, and I've changed my getter and my setter to use it. However, when I debug the code, I can see that the setter is never getting called. I can see that the dependency property is changing its value, but it's not setting the underlying controls' properties.

How can I make it so that the underlying controls have their properties set when the dependency property changes?

```
public partial class AccountSelector : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(AccountSelector));
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (UseComboBox)
                AccCombo.ItemsSource = value;
            else
                AccComplete.ItemsSource = value;
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the property's value being set but not being raised to the UI possibly? Also you declare the property as readonly which would prevent assigning to it except within a constructor or declaration of the same class. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) for more info on readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a propertyChangedCallback to your UIPropertyMetadata, like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(AccountSelector), new UIPropertyMetadata((d, e) =>
        {
            if (e.NewValue == null) return;

            var s = d as AccountSelector;
            var list = e.NewValue as IEnumerable;

            if (list == null || s == null) return;
            if (s.UseComboBox)
                s.AccCombo.ItemsSource = list;
            else
                s.AccComplete.ItemsSource = list;                
        }));
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: The setter shown here is wrong. It has to call `SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value)` and nothing else. See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for details.

Comment: So the logic on the setter has to be moved to the callback?

Comment: @RenanGemignani Exactly. No idea how you could have accepted this answer.

Comment: I just tested it and it seemed to work.

Comment: Two more notes. Checking `e.NewValue` and `list` for null is redundant. You may check `list` only. Then, a dynamic cast `d as AccountSelector` is wrong here, as you expect to have an AccountSelector instance in d and nothing else. Everything else is an error and should raise an `InvalidCastException`. So better write `var s = (AccountSelector)d`.

Comment: Finally, there is no need to use `UIPropertyMetadata`. You may as well use ordinary `PropertyMetadata`.